# Inno Setup: How to put the installer itself in the installed program

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I have an installer on Inno Setup that installs a program.
This installer has many forms for user input.
But if the user didn't type in the appropriate information, I would like to give him the option to reclick the installer and type in the appropriate information.
I tried to achive this like so:

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\myUser\Output\Setup.exe"; DestDir: "{app}";
```

But I get this following error when i run the code: (Source file "C:\Users\myUser\Output\Setup.exe" does not exist.)
So how can I put the installer itself in the installation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this might do what you want. It copies the setup binary file referred by the [`{srcexe}`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=srcexe) constant to the application directory given by the [`{app}`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=app) constant and does it *externally* by the [`external`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=external) flag, so the setup package doesn't need to *packed inside itself*. In other words, it just copies the executed setup to the application folder:

```
[Files]
Source: "{srcexe}"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: external
```

Comment: That's a cool feature, because the attempt to `FileCopy(ExpandConstant('{srcexe}'), somewhereelse, False)` always fails during the execution of srcexe.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the AppmodifiPath feature in [setup] section to add a 'modify' option in Windows Control panel 'Programs and feature' this way your user will be able to relaunch the setup and modify the path. Look below

[Setup]
AppModifyPath="{app}\mySetup.exe" /modify=1

[Files]
Source: "{srcexe}"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: external